# How to fetch variable value in testsuite from page in protractor?

Tags: protractor

**Protractor:**

I have defined variable on my page (`var rowcount`), now I want to use this value to create loop on test suite.

```
var rows = tabledata.all(by.tagName("tr"));
var cells = rows.all(by.tagName("td"));

var rowcount=rows.count;
```

Will this work?

```
if("Validate page data. ", function () 
{
    for(var i=0; i<rowscount;i++)
    {
        ................................
    }
})
```

Comment: If you want to loop over elements, just use Protractor's ElementArrayFinder `.each()` method.  No need to count the number before you loop.  And just FYI, `count()` returns a promise (and is also a function, so you are missing parenthesis in your code), you need to resolve it first before trying to access that value

Answer (score 0):

use it this way :

```
rows.count().then(function(count){
  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
 }
});
```

Comment: I want to fetch value on test suite, it is giving error  rowcount is not defined.

Comment: change it to `this.rows = tabledata.all(by.tagName("tr")); this.cells = rows.all(by.tagName("td"));` and then use it `this.rows.count().then(function(count){
  for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
 }
});`

Comment: Don't use a for loop with promises if you don't properly handle the promises within the for loop in a correct way it will fail executing the code in the for loop